# C++: how can I use parallel-for macro multiple times in same scope?

Tags: c++, macros, parallel.for

I'm using a local function definition to run a code block N times acting like a parallel-for version of C# but it gives multiple definition error for `f` function when I use two or more of it in same scope. How can I make the function name incrementally changed such as f1,f2,f3,.. after each usage in same scope?

---

Definition:

```
#ifndef PARALLEL_FOR
#define PARALLEL_FOR(N,O) \
                        struct LocalClass                                                           \
                        {                                                                           \
                            void operator()(int i) const O                                      \
                        } f;                                                                        \
                        std::thread threads[N];                                                     \
                        for(int loopCounterI=0; loopCounterI<N; loopCounterI++)                     \
                        {                                                                           \
                            threads[loopCounterI]=std::thread(f,loopCounterI);                      \
                        }                                                                           \
                        for(int loopCounterI=0; loopCounterI<N; loopCounterI++)                     \
                        {                                                                           \
                            threads[loopCounterI].join();                                           \
                        }                                                                           \

#endif
```

Usage:

```
PARALLEL_FOR(
        5,
        {std::cout<<100*i<<std::endl;}
);
```

output:

```
0
300
200
100
400
```

normally adding `{\` and `}\` would solve for consequent calls but what if I do nested parallel for?

Comment: You can use macro string concatenation, IE, `##`. So `LocalClass##Number`.

Comment: But I can't increment Number with using same macro 2 times. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Either pass a single other parameter, or use a complicated, overbearing way to track all indexes previously done. Just pass the count, like in the answer someone posted below.

Comment: If you technically wanted to, you could a global variable to count the number of indexes globally, and then increment inside the macro. I think passing the index is a better solution, IMO.

Comment: Okay, thank you. What about nested call loop-counter visibility? How would a function body definition see outer variables? Right now it sees only function's own parameters. Would it be stupid to ask this as a new question?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik If you need to call this macro from different functions you basically have 2 options: Either pass the index to the function or have a global variable that gets incremented inside the macro as said by someone previously. (Or if you're in a class you can have a member hold this index)

Comment: Why are you using a macro in the first place and not just a function?

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure, that c#'s parallel for doesn't start a separate thread for each loop pass - that would be incredible inefficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it doesn't seem like the ideal solution to me, you can concatenate strings in macros using `##`. In your code do the following

```
#ifndef PARALLEL_FOR
#define PARALLEL_FOR(N,O,usageInd) \
                    struct LocalClass##usageInd                                                           \
                    {                                                                           \
                        void operator()(int i) const O                                      \
                    } f##usageInd;                                                                        \
                    std::thread threads[N];                                                     \
                    for(int loopCounterI=0; loopCounterI<N; loopCounterI++)                     \
                    {                                                                           \
                        threads[loopCounterI]=std::thread(f##usageInd,loopCounterI);                      \
                    }                                                                           \
                    for(int loopCounterI=0; loopCounterI<N; loopCounterI++)                     \
                    {                                                                           \
                        threads[loopCounterI].join();                                           \
                    }                                                                           \

#endif
```

It would be up to you to now pass an index for each usage.

Comment: So I can call it "nested loop depth" then.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I'm not sure what you mean, but naming doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of passing a unique ID, you could use `__LINE__`.

But instead of an ugly macro, why don't you use a function with a lambda?

```
template <int N, class F>
void parallel_for(F f) {
    std::thread threads[N]; // or std::array<std::thread, N> threads;

    for(int loopCounterI=0; loopCounterI<N; loopCounterI++) {
        threads[loopCounterI]=std::thread(f,loopCounterI);
    }
    for(int loopCounterI=0; loopCounterI<N; loopCounterI++) {
        threads[loopCounterI].join();
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
parallel_for<5>([] (int i) {
    std::cout<<100*i<<std::endl;
});
```

The lambda can capture the variables you need:

```
int j = ...;
parallel_for<5>([j] (int i) {
    std::cout<<100*(i+j)<<std::endl;
});
```

Comment: This is better than using a macro. Using a function to do this is much more elegant than using such an ugly macro